# Storage Plugin for Oracle DB in Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

I am trying to configure for Oracle DB. But showing: Error

> Error(Not able to create and update storage.)

```
{
    type: "jdbc",
    enabled: true,
    driver: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
    url:"jdbc:oracle:thin:system/pass@123@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8047/nvn"
}
```

Please tell what i am doing wrong in this..?

Comment: Did you restart drill after adding `ojdbc7.jar`?

Comment: Ya.. i restart the drill

Comment: check logs in `apache-drill-1.4.0/log/sqlline.log`. Is anything mentioned there regarding this failure?

Comment: This Error Coming in log:-------   2016-01-28 17:04:11,980 [main] INFO  o.a.drill.common.config.DrillConfig - Configuration and plugin file(s) identified in 166ms.
Base Configuration:
 - jar:file:/F:/apache-drill-1.4.0/apache-drill-1.4.0/jars/drill-common-1.4.0.jar!/drill-default.conf

Intermediate Configuration and Plugin files, in order of precedence:
 - jar:file:/F:/apache-drill-1.4.0/apache-drill-1.4.0/jars/drill-common-1.4.0.jar!/drill-module.conf

Comment: This error is showing in log file

Comment: This log does not contain error information. Edit your question with relevant logs came after adding this plugin

Comment: Also is there any error shown on drill's shell when plugin addition fails ?

Comment: Hey... It doesn't have any error in log file. while creating new storage plugin for oracle. I tried.. I remove all the log and try to create new  plugin for oracle... again it showing error (unable to create or update plugin). and not having any error in log.

Comment: Are you able to add this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with **url** of storage plugin.

You need to mention Oracle machnie's hostname/IP & port not Drill Web UI's URL.

```
url:"jdbc:oracle:thin:<username>/<password>@<oracle-machine-hostname>:<port>/SID"
```

Eg:

```
url:"jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@192.168.xx.xx:1521/orcl"
```

**NOTE:**

1. Make sure `ojdbc7.jar` is added in `<drill-directory>/jars/3rdparty`
2. Double check your **connection url, username, password** via JDBC client or code using JDBC jar

Comment: 2016-02-24 11:09:50,105 [main] INFO  o.a.d.c.s.persistence.ScanResult - loading 6 classes for org.apache.drill.common.logical.FormatPluginConfig took 0ms
2016-02-24 11:09:51,058 [main] INFO  o.a.drill.exec.server.rest.WebServer - Setting up HTTP connector for web server
2016-02-24 11:09:52,041 [main] INFO  o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Startup completed (3947 ms).
 This is error showing in log file

Comment: Which IP address and port number should give while configuring storage plugin..? Whether to give oracle IP :-127.0.0.1:8080 or my PC IP..???

Comment: I have given the same IP.. still having problem..?

Comment: same IP means IP of oracle & oracle's port in URL? If yes, then use \"pass@123\" instead of pass@123 in url

Comment: @NaveenD you don't need to accept my answer as your issue is not resolved.

Comment: @NaveenD Did changing password in url help you?

Comment: @NaveenD Before adding plugins for RDBMS in drill URL, username, password should be verified via JDBC client or JDBC code. If these parameters are fine, Drill will surely add that plugin.

Comment: Before oracle connection.. I have successfully created connection fro SQL Server, but In case of oracle db i am facing problem..The Same configuration for oracle is working throught c# code.. But while creating storage plugin i am facing problem... And DEV Please tell whether to use drill in live project for big data. because in some site i found that it is new and ready for production environment.

Comment: I am using oracle plugin & it's working. I agree that Drill is new. But this is a great tool & it's community is very active. People are adding more features in every release. Now for **it can be used for live project in big data** I would say depend on your use case. You should do a POC first. If it's satisfying your use case, you can go ahead for that. Spark SQL is another option if you want SQL layer over big data.

Comment: Ya i understand.. Dev please tell whether drill works for excel and ms access file..?

Comment: work with excel means you want to query over csv files or excel as BI tool to generate reports,etc?

Comment: means I want  to access xslx file throught drill.?  And What about ms access files..?

Comment: actually I have not use drill to query over excel, ms acess. I use it for hive, oracle, teradata, hdfs, csv, json files. So, it would be better you ask for details on **Drill User Community**. Post a query over mail to: user@drill.apache.org

Comment: Thanks dev.. but what about oracle storage plugin..? Would know any solution for that..

Comment: I told you all the things in my mind. Updated my answer again

Comment: Hey.. I am using oracle express edition.. does it make any difference in storage plugin..??

Comment: I simply uninstall the oracle and again install it and change the password. I think password (pass@123)was creating problem. Now Its Working Perfectly. Thanks Dev for ur help and giving time.

Comment: @NaveenD Happy to help. I think "@" cloud cause problem. I provided you solution on the basis of this article: http://nadvi.blogspot.in/2011/02/oracle-password-with-or-special.html

Comment: Thanks for ur help

Comment: What are the query Apache Drill can support...? Means only select query or other query...?

Comment: only select queries for RDBMS. Check [SQL reference](https://drill.apache.org/docs/sql-reference/) for details. BTW what types of query do you want to perform ?

Comment: which one is useful for taking data from different data sources(different DBs) distributed or embeded?

Comment: embedded mode is for testing. In live project, distributed mode should be used (with number of nodes depending upon your load and all)

Comment: if i used embedded mode in live project, does it effect anything or any problem or benefit.??

Comment: Apache drill is a software to handle big data. For low amount of data you can jdbc for RDBMS & client jars for NoSQL databases. You can't handle large data with a single machine. You need a cluster for that. You need distributed computing for better performance. Hence, you need distributed mode if volume of data that you want to process is large.